# saving data from for loop to single list

Tags: python

I have a file upload page where users upload their files and they are generally bunch of files.In my python code I am trying to pull a tag out from that file and then save it into a list, so everything works fine but here I am getting three different output lists for 3 files uploaded. How do I combine the 3 output lists into just one.Here is my code

```
    a=self.filename
    print(a) #this prints out the uploaded file names(ex: a.xml,b.xml,c.xml)
    soc_list=[]
    for soc_id in self.tree.iter(tag='SOC_ID'):
        req_soc_id = soc_id.text
        soc_list.append(req_soc_id)
    print(soc_list)
```

the output I get is:

```
    a.xml
    ['1','2','3']
    b.xml
    [4,5,6]
    c.xml
    [7,8,9]
```

I would like to combine all into just one list

Comment: can you not do `combinedlist = [ listA + listB + listC ]` ?, that should give you all list in one.

Comment: Each and every time I get a different file, so its not possible to do a+b+c. Sometimes they may upload 12 files

Comment: You have to describe your context a bit more. For example, is the code you gave part of a loop that iterates over every file that's uploaded, or are you starting your code three times to produce the output you describe?

Comment: @user8521874: how are you getting your output. Are you executing some function 3 times (for above example) or you are executing once. You can always concatenate lists.Can you provide more details of function and context / process.

Comment: function gets executed the number of times the files are uploaded, So if i upload 3 files it executes 3 times

Comment: @user8521874 its not going to happen the way you think if your not gonna save those list values somehwere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I analyzed I think you want to write all the soc_list values to a single file and then you can read the file back. Doing this would be the best way for you **because you will not know the user file uploads as you mentioned in your question**. To do so try to understand and implement this code below to save to your file

```
    save_path = "your_path_goes_here"
    name_of_file = "your_file_name"
    completeName = os.path.join(save_path, name_of_file + ".txt")
    file1 = open(completeName, 'a')
    for soc_id in self.tree.iter(tag='SOC_ID'):
        req_soc_id = soc_id.text
        soc_list.append(req_soc_id)
        file1.write(req_soc_id)
        file1.write("\n")
    file1.close()
```

This way you can always write things to your file and then to read back your data and converting it into list follow this example as below

```
    examplefile = open(fileName, 'r')
    yourResult = [line.split('in_your_case_newline_split') for line in examplefile.readlines()]
```